# What is the difference between temperature difference and temperature change?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

In a course of mathematical modelling that I am taking, there is a great confusion between the concepts of temperature change due to a unit heat input at some position $x$ and time $t$, and the temperature distribution due to a unit heat input at some position $x$ and time $t$.

The instantaneous plane source solution is:
$$T\left ( x,t \right )=\frac{Q'}{2\sqrt{\pi \kappa t}}e^{-x^{2}/4\kappa t}$$
Now, my book attempts to connect the idea of temperature distribution. It denotes the temperature distribution due to the release of a unit of heat per unit area at $x=0$ and $t=0$ in an infinite region by $G(x,t)$:
$$G\left ( x,t \right )= \begin{cases}
0, &\forall t< 0 \\ 
\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-x^{2}/4\kappa t},& \forall t> 0\end{cases}$$
where 
$$\mu= \frac{1}{2\rho c\sqrt{\pi \kappa}}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi \kappa c \rho}} $$

Would someone be nice enough to explain to me the idea of temperature distribution and how it relates to temperature change?

Is temperature distribution $G(x,t)=\frac{T(x,t)}{Q'}$?

Edit: Thanks for cleaning up.

Comment: As for the question in the title: a *temperature change* would be something like $T(x,t_1) - T(x,t_0)$, i.e. the change in temperature *at a particular point* over time. A *temperature difference* is something like $T(x_2,t) - T(x_1,t)$, i.e. the difference in temperature between *two different points in space* at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first expression is a *temperature distribution*: it simply tells you the temperature  $T$ at each point in the $x,t$ space.

Now if you, using that formula, calculated two temperatures $T_1$ (at $x_1,t_1)$ and $T_2$ (at $x_2,t_2)$, then the difference:

$$\Delta T=T_2-T_1,$$

is an actual *temperature difference*. An *infinitesimal* temperature difference would be written as $\partial T$.

You'll probably need to use *infinitesimal* temperature differences to calculate how your temperature distribution evolves in time because you indicate there's heat input. Fourier's Law of heat conduction:

$$\large{q=-\kappa \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}},$$

where $q$ is the heat flux and $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$ a temperature *gradient* (ratio of two infinitesimal differences), is usually needed to solve that kind of problem. What Fourier really means is that heat conduction is favoured by greater temperature gradients.

**Edit:** (in answer to OP's comment)

We can re-write OP's first equation as:

$T(x,t)=Q'f(x,t)$

Dividing both sides by $Q'$ we get using OP's notation:

$G(x,t)=f(x,t),$ where $f(x,t)$:

$f\left ( x,t \right )=\dfrac{e^{-x^{2}/4\kappa t}}{2\sqrt{\pi \kappa t}}.$

*By definition* $G(x,t)$ cannot be a temperature distribution, although it clearly is a (Gaussian) distribution in $x,t$. I suspect the author will want to use this distribution further down in his derivation.

You can also work out the unit of measurement of $G(x,t)$: it is not $\mathrm{K}$, the unit of temperature.

Comment: If the first expression is a temperature distribution then what exactly is the expression G(x,t)=....?
The author mentioned that G is also temperature distribution.

Comment: @Physkid: I've edited my response into the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.
On a tangent, why is T=Q'f?
Any physical insights?

Comment: @Physkid: I believe Q' is a heat flux. Multiplied with the distribution function f, it gives the temperature distribution T of your system. Thanks for the upvote.